# Deleting Rosetta 2 cache after a certain number of days

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, rosetta

Rosetta 2 apparently caches every time you execute a program for the first time and then saves that to `/var/db/oah`. I looked at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427695/how-can-i-limit-the-disk-usage-of-the-rosetta-2-oah-cache) post for reference, and they said that you can create a `cron` script to automatically delete everything in the folder every 30 days. I have no clue how to do that, so any help would be appreciated. The .aot files are taking up over 100 MB so it would be great if I could delete them after every initial execution.

Comment: Figured out how to delete files in `/var/db/oah`. Just had to disable System Integrity Protection.

Comment: Please, could you answer your own question, by telling more details about the erase procedure?  I have a similar issue as you.  Could we safely erase all the .aot files in there?